# Vertically center font awesome icon next to a bigger one

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've read dozens of related questions, tried using all solutions however none seem to work. Am I missing something? Here's screenshot:
The problem is these arrows arent in the middle of bigger icons.
[image]

CSS:

```
    span.fa {
  font-size: 50px;
}
i.fa {
  font-size: 120px;
  text-align: center !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s;
}
i.fa-map-signs {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  color: #00b6ff;
}
i.fa-pencil {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  color: #00b6ff;
}
i.fa-credit-card {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  color: #00b6ff;
}
i.fa-hand-peace-o {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  color: #00b6ff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-grey text-center">
  <h2 style="margin-bottom: 100px;">Kaip tai veikia?</h2>
  <div class="row slideanim">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <i class="fa fa-map-signs" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i>
      <p>Susirandate norimą kursą bei datą</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <span class="fa fa-arrow-right" style="vertical-align: middle;"></font>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
      <p>Užsiregistruojate į norimą kursą</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
      <p>Susimokate</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <i class="fa fa-hand-peace-o"></i>
      <p>Viskas!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using bootstrap by the way.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `line-height` on `span.fa` equal to the `font-size` of your other icons:

```css
span.fa {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 120px;
}

i.fa {
  font-size: 120px;
  text-align: center !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s;
}

i.fa-map-signs {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  color: #00b6ff;
}

i.fa-pencil {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  color: #00b6ff;
}

i.fa-credit-card {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  color: #00b6ff;
}

i.fa-hand-peace-o {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  color: #00b6ff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid bg-grey text-center">
  <h2 style="margin-bottom: 100px;">Kaip tai veikia?</h2>
  <div class="row slideanim">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <i class="fa fa-map-signs" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i>
      <p>Susirandate norimą kursą bei datą</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <span class="fa fa-arrow-right" style="vertical-align: middle;"></font>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
      <p>Užsiregistruojate į norimą kursą</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
      <p>Susimokate</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <i class="fa fa-hand-peace-o"></i>
      <p>Viskas!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: damn, such a simple line yet I couldn't figure it out myself. Thank you man!